# Two startup applications icons with cinnamon

Tags: gnome, 13.10, cinnamon, startup-applications

After installing cinnamon, many settings were duplicated such as "Power", "Screensaver", etc.  I was able to remove most of it with `sudo apt-get purge gnome-control-center`.

"Startup Applications" is still duplicated.  How do I remove the gnome version?

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean? A screenshot would be really helpful.

Comment: Did you added the official cinnamon repo? Such as:
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable

Comment: Actually I check mine and I have the same :p. In fact I have the double of a bunch of things, bluetooth, network settings, power management, region and language, sound, startup application, system settings, universal access and user accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get purge gnome-session` will get rid of any duplication among `cinnamon-session` and `gnome-session` for the latest cinnamon.

Follow [Presbitero's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/399679/128334) to get rid of the icon in Menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the menu and remove manually each of the duplicates.

To edit the menu just:

Right click on the menu icon -> configure -> Open the menu editor.

[image: Menu edit]